# web services large fail upload to 2010 site failed error connection reset

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

Using java web service to upload files to share point 2010 site, it is failing to upload large size files due to connection reset by peer, as per the share point admin it is 401 authorization for connection drop, which need of credentials.

Is their any way that i can ensure from web services side the connection is alive until upload finishes.